# スマートフォンやPCブラウザでのgenerators(yield)の対応状況とコールバック地獄対策について

Tags: javascript

Javascriptのコールバック地獄から抜け出す方法としてJavascript1.7から使えるようになるgeneratorsを利用する方法は色々と話題になったと思いますが、現在普及しているスマートフォンやPCのブラウザでgeneratorsを使うということはどれだけ現実的なのでしょうか？

Javascript1.7に対応しているブラウザを調査してみているのですが、Firefoxしか対応していないなど、古い情報が出てきたりして、いまいち現在どの程度対応されているのかわかりませんでした。

根本的な解決にはなっていないものの、コールバック地獄をライブラリレベルで抜け出すもう一つの方法として、`jQuery.Deferred`を利用する方法も有名かと思われますが、最近`RxJS`や`Bacon.js`の存在を知り、現在のトレンドとして皆様がどのようにコールバック地獄と向き合っているのか疑問に思っています。

そこで皆様に質問したいのですが

1. これから作るウェブサービスにgeneratorsを使うことについてどう思うか？
2. generatorsを利用しない場合、どのようにコールバック地獄対策をしているか

ということについて皆様の意見を教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[各ブラウザの ES6 Generators の対応状況](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#generators)を見るに、未だ実用レベルではありません。
利用する場合は、Polyfill が必須になります。
仕様は Fix しているので、Polyfill 込であれば利用することを考えるのもありだと思っています。

ES6 Generators の Polyfill としては、Facebook の [regenerator](http://facebook.github.io/regenerator/) が有名です。
[Babel](http://babeljs.io/) (ES6 全般を ES5 に変換してくれるツール) でも、ES6 Generators に関しては regenerator が利用されています。

私は Babel はよく利用していますが、regenerator は本格的に使ったことはありません。
が、検証してみる価値はあると思っています。